# passing list of argument to class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have written a class which produces desired output when correct attributes (10 of them) are passed.
Now, I am trying to pass lists of these attributes to the class, but getting an error.

Could anyone, please, give me a good example of passing a list (or lists) of attributes to a class (a class which has methods involving pow() and log() functions)?

Thank you in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Post your current code, what you've tried, and the error message.

Comment: look at [`*args`](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Unfortunately, can't post the code (confidentiality issues with the math functions in it). It's going to take me a while to write a similar code. I feel like I am missing something really simple. Therefore, asked for a good example.

Comment: @gionni, Thanks a lot, mate :)

Comment: maybe something like `def __init__(self, **kwargs)` so you can pass a dict of attributes when initializing your class instance (look at [**kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs#3394898))